# Multiple strings in openURL. iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, twitter, openurl

I am making a twitter application for iPhone, I am trying to add a button which will open Safari, and take the user to their twitter homepage. I have a textfield called username, so the following code does not work, hopefully someone will be able to help me out.

```
-(IBAction)viewAccount {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/", username.text]];

}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.twitter.com/%@", username.text]]];
```

Comment: You might want to mark this question as answered so it wouldn't show up in the unanswered list anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your URL is correct

```
NSURL* twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/", username.text];
NSLog(@"my twitter url: %@", twitterURL);
```

edit: seems someone was faster than me ;)